# How to draw this equation of point (U, V)

Tags: elliptic-equations

$ U = 9 - 3 \cos(2t) + 8.5 \sin(2 t) $

$ V = 5.5 - 0.5 \cos(2t) + 6 \sin(2t) $

1)How to know the point (U, V) will form an ellipse?

2)How to draw it?

3)Is there any tool which can display this path?

Attempt:

I read the wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse

And so far, I only know how to draw the path **on paper** like:

$\frac{\left(x-x_\circ\right)^2}{a^2}+\frac{\left(y-y_\circ\right)^2}{b^2}=1\mathrm{~.}$

Shifted ellipse
If the standard ellipse is shifted to have center ${\displaystyle \left(x_{\circ },\,y_{\circ }\right)}$

The axes are still parallel to the x- and y-axes.

Comment: Desmos works, you just need to change up some variables

Comment: Otherwise, use Geogebra as it works really well.

Comment: I visited the two websites: https://www.desmos.com/ and https://www.geogebra.org/, but do not find way how to put 2 equation and let it draw an ellipse, could you elabrate more?
@AaaLol_dude

Comment: @AaaLol_dude could you show how to use the 2 website to draw this plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $r(t) = (U(t), V(t))$ then

$ r(t) = C +  V_1 \cos(2 t) + V_2 \sin(2 t) $

where

$C = \begin{bmatrix} 9 \\ 5.5 \end{bmatrix}, \ V_1 = \begin{bmatrix} -3 \\ -0.5 \end{bmatrix}, \ V_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 8.5 \\ 6 \end{bmatrix} $

Define the unit vector

$ u = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(2t) \\ \sin(2t) \end{bmatrix} $

Then

$ r = C + A u $

where

$ A = \begin{bmatrix} -3 && 8.5 \\ -0.5 && 6 \end{bmatrix} $

Therefore,

$ u = A^{-1} (r - C) $

And since $u^T u = 1 $ , then this means that

$ (r - C)^T G (r - c) = 1 $

where $G = A^{-T} A^{-1} $

Numerically, we have

$G = \begin{bmatrix} 0.191735537 && -0.27768595 \\ -0.27768595 && 0.429752066 \end{bmatrix} $

Diagonalizing $G$, we can express it as follows:

$ G = R D R^T $

where

$ D = \begin{bmatrix} 0.008630488 && 0 \\ 0 && 0.612857115 \end{bmatrix} $

and

$ R = \begin{bmatrix} 0.834841092 && -0.550491009 \\ 0.550491009 && 8.834841092 \end{bmatrix} $

If we define the vector $w =  R^T (r - C) $ then

$w^T D w = 1 $

expanding this expression, we obtain,

$ \dfrac{w_1^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{w_2^2}{b^2} = 1 $

where

$ a^2 = \dfrac{1 }{0.008630488} = 115.8682983 $

$ b^2 = \dfrac{1}{ 0.612857115} = 1.631701706 $

So vector $w$ traces an ellipse of semi-major axis length equal to

$a = \sqrt{115.8682983} = 10.76421378 $

and a semi-minor axis length equal to

$ b = \sqrt{ 1.631701706 } = 1.277380799 $

The $w$-ellipse is in standard position, with its major axis parallel to the horizontal axis, and its minor axis parallel to the vertical axis.  From the above definition of $w$, we have that

$ r = C + R w  $

Hence, $r$ is on a translated and rotated ellipse in the (U, V) plane.  The translation from the origin is by the vector $C$, and the rotation is counter clockwise by an angle of $\theta = \tan^{-1} \left( \dfrac{ 0.550491009}{0.834841092} \right) = 33.40070474^\circ $

Using all this information, we can now attempt to plot the ellipse that represents $r = (U,V)$.

The major semi-axis is of length $10.76421378$ and is rotated by $\theta =33.40070474^\circ$ degrees in the counter clockwise direction.  Therefore, the vector representing it is

$ X_1 = 10.76421378 (\cos \theta, \sin \theta) $

And the minor semi-axis is of length $1.277380799$ and it is rotated from the vertical direction by the same angle $\theta$ (counter clockwise).  Hence, the vector representing the minor semi-axis is

$ X_2 = 1.277380799 (- \sin \theta, \cos \theta ) $

Now, we have a different parametrization of the ellipse that we started with, and it is as follows

$ r = C + X_1 \cos(s) + X_2 \sin(s), \ s \in [0, 2\pi] $

From this expression we can plot the ellipse, by substituting uniformly spaced values of $s$ over $[0, 2 \pi ]$, then connecting the dots.

This what I did using Excel, and obtained the following graph

[image]

Comment: Let me digest it, it seems it has more knowledge than high school math. @Hosam H

Comment: If you're in high school, it might be difficult for you to grasp some of the formulas in my solution.

Comment: I am not familiar with Geogebra and desmos.  If you are, then you can plot the parametric equation directly using either, without the need to find the semi-major and semi-minor axes and the tilt angle first.

Comment: Currently it is difficult to under how to draw it, by the way, how do you know the maximum ratio $\frac{}{} $ occurs at =6,=5?

Comment: You're talking about your previous problem.  In that problem after plotting the part of the ellipse corresponding to the interval of $t \in [0, \dfrac{\pi}{2}] $, you can see by inspecting the plot, that the maximum $U$ to $V$ ratio (and this ratio is the slope of the line segment connecting the origin to the point $(U, V)$ ) you can see that this ratio is maximum at $U = 6$ and $V = 5$.

Comment: May I ask how you know that the largest slope of the line segment connecting the origin (0, 0) to the point (,). It seems that it is when $t = \frac{\pi}{2}.$.

What is the graph meaning of $t$ and $\theta$? Could you demonstrate it on the plot?

Comment: Or is there online textbook or material to demonstrate this different parametrization of the ellipse?